# Linker Error Lunatic Python lua.require('socket') -> undefined symbol: lua_getmetatable

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, lua

I have a python project that relies on some lua files, one of which requires 'socket'.  I get an error loading socket.core "undefined symbol: lua_getmetatable" when I try to require that lua file from python 2.7.

Simple reproducer:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lua
>>> lua.require('socket')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: error: error loading module 'socket.core' from file 
    '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so':
    /usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_getmetatable
```

I am using a [recent Lunatic Python branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~hircus/lunatic-python/trunk) where I cleaned up the Py_ssize_t warnings, and liblua5.1-socket2 on Ubuntu 11.04

I get the same error if I use the main lunatic-python source code and/or upgrade to [luasocket 2.0.2](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/).

edit: What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

edit #2: Here is the output of building luasocket-2.0.2.  The default make did not build unix.so, and I edited it to build that as well so I didn't mix and match 2.0.0 with 2.0.2:

```
$ make
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/sandbox/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2/src'
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o luasocket.o luasocket.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o timeout.o timeout.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o buffer.o buffer.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o io.o io.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o auxiliar.o auxiliar.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o options.o options.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o inet.o inet.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o tcp.o tcp.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o udp.o udp.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o except.o except.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o select.o select.c
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o usocket.o usocket.c
gcc  -O -shared -fpic -o socket.so.2.0.2 luasocket.o timeout.o buffer.o io.o auxiliar.o options.o inet.o tcp.o udp.o except.o select.o usocket.o 
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o mime.o mime.c
gcc  -O -shared -fpic -o mime.so.1.0.2 mime.o 
gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -DLUASOCKET_DEBUG  -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fpic -llua   -c -o unix.o unix.c
gcc  -O -shared -fpic -o unix.so buffer.o auxiliar.o options.o timeout.o io.o usocket.o unix.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/sandbox/luasocket/luasocket-2.0.2/src'
```

Comment: What is the question, though? ;)

Comment: What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The symbols are not correctly exported from the `lua` module that could be used in module it requires. Could you also post a log of the compilation stage, mainly the final linking part?

Comment: @MichalKottman Added compile and link output to the original question.

Comment: have you tried to run `ldconfig`? if `/usr/lib/lua/5.1` is a symbolic link then `echo "/path/to/lue5.1/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/lua51.conf && ldconfig`

Comment: /usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so is a symlink to /usr/lib/liblua5.1-socket.so.2.0.0  Adding /usr/lib or even /usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket as suggested by @JFSebastian (with elevated privs) has no affect on the error.  I think it's finding the right so, as the error complains about /usr/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in `luasocket`, but in the way symbols from shared libraries are handled.

The problem is that the while the `lua.so` (Python module) links to `liblua5.1.so`, shared modules loaded by `require` do not have access to the symbols from `liblua5.1.so`. On Mac OS X this works, because symbols from `dlopen` are loaded as `RTLD_GLOBAL` by default.

I have experimented with modifying the Lua source (`lua-5.1.4/src/loadlib.c:69`), however it does not help, because by the time `require` is called from `lua.so`, the symbols from `liblua5.1.so` have already been loaded locally for `lua.so`. This is why `luasocket` does not see them.

Fortunately, Python allows you to change the `dlopen` semantics using the `sys` module. This allows you to force to load modules with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, which is exactly what is needed. Try running the following code and see if it works for you:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, DLFCN
>>> sys.setdlopenflags(DLFCN.RTLD_NOW | DLFCN.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>>> import lua
>>> lua.require("socket")
<Lua table at 0x22ccef0>
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks for the great explanation too.  For the curious, you can learn more about ldload via 'man ldload' and the [Python docs for the sys module](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).  sys.setdlopenflags( n ) is unix only.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem except on the lua side instead of python. I tried rebuilding lunatic with `-export-dynamic` hoping that symbols it depends on would be visible to subsequent modules loaded later -- it didn't work. Out of curiosity, why doesn't this problem happen on windows?