# Error while installing lua socket

Tags: sockets, error-handling, path, lua

I am using `lua 5.1` in a linux system.I installed the `luasocket 2.0.2` using this [manual](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/).But when i execute the below code of the file `test.lua`

```
socket = require("socket")
print(socket._VERSION)
```

I get the following errors :

```
lua: ./usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua:14: loop or previous error loading module 'socket'

stack traceback:

    [C]: in function 'require'

    ./usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua:14: in main chunk

    [C]: in function 'require'

    test.lua:1: in main chunk

    [C]: ?
```

But i have included the environmental variable as below:

```
LUA_PATH=/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;?.lua

LUA_CPATH=/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;?.so
```

Answer (score 2):

You usually get this error when you have a loop in your `require` calls, for example, when you do `require "socket"` and from that module you do `require "socket"` again, before the first `require` call is finished.

Check line 14 in `socket.lua` file. It should probably have something like `local socket = require("socket.core")` (and not `require("socket")`). To check if the issue is with loading `socket.core`, try executing `require "socket.core"` in your own script as it may give you a better error message.

Comment: bt now there is an error "error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so':
 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: luaL_getmetatable"

Comment: You may want to check this SO question and the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361437/linker-error-lunatic-python-lua-requiresocket-undefined-symbol-lua-getme